# can't view payment section in cachfree

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, payment

I integrated the cachfree payment gateway in laravel but i am facing issues; its redirecting to the page `https://payments-test.cashfree.com/order/#85**********dW`.

But when I get to "This payment is created in Test Mode. No money will actually be debited for this." section, I can't view the section below, which includes card, UPI, wallet etc. The console displays an [error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xiILe.png)

I have tried various methods like -

```php
$url = "https://sandbox.cashfree.com/pg/orders"; 
$url = "https://sandbox.cashfree.com/pg/links";
```